# jQuery Highcharts: change chart type using dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

i'm trying to change the value of chart as following

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script>
var chart1; // globally available

$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = 'pie'
    $("select").change(function(){
        chart = $('#chart').val();
        alert(chart);
    });

   chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
       chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: chart 
        },
        yAxis: {
           title: {
              text: 'Temprature'
           }
        },
        series: [{
           name: 'mach_1',
            data: [<?php 
            foreach($chart as $`row) {
            echo  $row['temp'].",";
            }
           ?>]
          }]
      });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="form">

    <label>Select a chart : </label>
    <select id="chart">
      <option>pie</option>
      <option>column</option>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div id="container"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

i know this will change the value of chart on select, but it doesn't change the chart itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Please reformat your code, it is not possible to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Your original question was very difficult to read and interpret; some of stackoverflow's code editor tags were intertwined with the code you attempted to post. In the future, it may help to put an example of your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).
2. If I'm understanding the question correctly, you are looking to change the type of chart displayed. Show a pie chart of the data; now show a bar graph of the data; now show a line chart, etc.
3. When you have a Highcharts question, it's a good bet someone else has asked that question before on the Highcharts forum. In your case, I think this is true: "Change chart type dynamically?" - http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5501&p=26274&hilit=switch+chart+types#p26274
4. In the Highcharts forum question linked above, Highcharts author Torstein Honsi answers the question and includes a fiddle you may find to be a useful starting point, as he's changing the chart type in it. http://jsfiddle.net/tccpT/  Later on, a Highcharts support team member includes a fiddle where we see another example of changing the chart type. http://jsfiddle.net/2hLr5/
5. When a pie chart involves more than two pieces of data, it is generally advisable to not use a pie chart as a means of visualizing data. The more values a pie chart has, the more difficult it becomes to perceive the relationships between those pieces of data.