# Highcharts: How to Change type of Graph

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am usign Highcharts plugin for Graphs... this is my code:

```
$(function () {
            $('#graph1').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: mesesGraph1
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'WO / month'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: arrayFocal
            });
        });
```

Now I want a button that onclick() changes the type of my graph... is there a way to do this?

Comment: havn't used highcharts but try `$('#graph1').highcharts({chart:{type:'line'}});` or will that reset all the options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Highcharts: change chart type using dropdown list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948651/jquery-highcharts-change-chart-type-using-dropdown-list). Pretty similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the type by updating the type. Here is an example that works on normal buttons:

```
// Set type
$.each(['line', 'column', 'spline', 'area', 'areaspline', 'scatter'], function(i, type) {
  $('#' + type).click(function() {
    $.each(chart.series, function(j, series) {
      series.update({
        type: type
      });
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see, the buttons are anchored on the type and onClick each series in the chart is updated to whichever button you pressed. It's just as easy to do it directly on the graph, you just set the click event to update the series.

Also, my "chart" instance would be the following in your case:

```
var chart = $('#graph1').highcharts();
```

Comment: Yes, that solution will work for almost all series. For example 'bar' won't work - in that case, you will need to destroy and recreate chart.

Comment: Correct. It's also worth noting that if you're using Highstock instead, it also works but sometimes breaks. I've been playing with it to figure out why it breaks but nothing yet.

Comment: it worked... but I need to do this in two graphs on the same page... it works fine in the first graph... but on the second when I try to change the type, it doesnt show the bars again

Comment: can you show us a fiddle and/or the error logs? it's likely you're not anchoring the buttons correctly or maybe you're assigning the wrong variable to your second chart.